# Append a list and shift it up from the bottom

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a list that I'm trying to populate from the bottom up. The list takes an area that is 900 px tall. Each element on the list is 73 px tall. I would like to have each item slide up into the list.

I'm using .append() to add a new list item to my list but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make the list continue to slide up as items are appended to it. I can set the css attributes for my first list item to position:relative, top: 900 and then animate the list item up using .animate() shifting the item 900-73 px. That's as far as I get and then things go horribly wrong.

Please help?

Comment: so you want the inserted item to always appear at the top then?

Comment: Could you please us [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to upload an example of your code.

Comment: Check out `instertAfter()` and `insertBefore()`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a combination of CSS and jQuery. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/finbarr/HGugB/

It may look as though nothing happens when you click the first few times - scroll your browser window down as the items are being added from the bottom.

Comment: Holy poop! You're awesome. Thank you soo much!

Comment: No problem. It would also be possible to remove the list elements from the DOM that have been "popped off" from the top of the list, but I don't think you'll need to do this unless the list can grow to many thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're after something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Exjbb/

```
$(".container").prepend(element).find(":first").slideUp(0).slideDown("fast");
```

Comment: Very close. I want the list to grow from the bottom up. Not top down.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nbUuh/
You can add stuff to the list, and it will grow upwards.

Your question could use some clearer wording.